# Python Virtualbox API

Tags: python

http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/pyvb.vm.vbVM-class.html

there is a parameter **kw in        **init**(self, **kw)
what is it?

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary of arbitrary keyword arguments. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

If it really is a question about that concrete API, then please excuse me, I was typing faster than thinking.

Answer (score 0):

**kw is short for **kwargs. Additional named aguments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a dictionary of options from [the source](http://enomalism.com/api/pyvb/pyvb.vm-pysrc.html#vbVM.__init__)?